# iptables logging how to increase max log prefix?

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, iptables, logging

I have many iptables rules that will log offending packets.  My logs go to `/var/log/iptables.log` but the logs appear in 24-hour time: `Mar 13 00:13:55 kernel: DROPPED Attempted ping`, I would like them to appear in 12-hour AM/PM time.  I already found a way to get the date and time the rule was offended in the log with `--log-prefix "$(date +%B" "%d" "%r) DROPPED Port scan:`.  My issue is that the iptables `--log-prefix` is limited to 29-30 characters, I need a way to change the max length of the `--log-prefix` option. I've tried editing the source and re-compiling, but I get errors (only when using -j LOG) saying something is the wrong version (even though the source is the same version as the release I had before)

Answer (score 1):

> I already found a way to get the date and time the rule was offended in the log with `--log-prefix "$(date +%B" "%d" "%r)`

No, that just provides date and time the rule was *created*. If you use this, you'll just keep getting messages with the exact same timestamp forever.

iptables rules aren't evaluated by the shell for every single packet; they're processed once, uploaded to the kernel, and so the *kernel* would need to support any sort of expansions within the log-prefix.

(But it won't, because -j LOG messages go to the kernel log which already has numeric time­stamps, and it's the job of the log collector software to convert them into your preferred format.)

> My logs go to /var/log/iptables.log but the logs appear in 24-hour time: [...] I would like them to appear in 12-hour AM/PM time

The files `/var/log/*.log` are normally created by a *syslog* service (e.g. syslog-ng, rsyslog, sysklogd). Edit their configuration in order to change the timestamp format.

For example, if your logs are collected by syslog-ng, define a [template](https://www.syslog-ng.com/technical-documents/doc/syslog-ng-open-source-edition/3.16/administration-guide/58):

```
template t_12hour_file {
    template("[$DAY/$YEAR/$MONTH $HOUR12:$MIN:$SEC $AMPM] $MSGHDR$MSG\n");
};
destination d_iptables {
    file("/var/log/iptables.log" template(t_12hour_file));
};
```

See also [rsyslog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49449301/how-to-change-timestamp-format-on-rsyslog).

Comment: The script that shows the date/time the rule was offended does work, I've tested it.  I've also read that there is no way to change the format of the time in syslog

Comment: All that aside, I think blocking "Attempted ping" is already a bit silly; blocking _and logging_ ping attempts twice as much.

Comment: No, there's only no way to change the format in the syslog _network protocol_ (which has to be fixed because the sender and receiver must agree), but it is perfectly possible to change the format in the syslog _files_. It does work; I've tested it.

Comment: What files need to be changed to make my iptables logs (they appear in kern.log) appear in 12 hour time?

Comment: Well, what syslog daemon are you using to generate the kern.log file?

Comment: Dumb it down please lol I am not very well educated in linux.  The closest thing I can give you to an answer to that question is rsyslogd

Comment: For rsyslog edit `/etc/rsyslog.conf` according to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49449301/how-to-change-timestamp-format-on-rsyslog

Comment: That is supposed to change me to 12-hour time?

Comment: I've checked again and it turns out rsyslog only has 24-hour `%hour%` expansion. Sounds like you'll need to edit the source of rsyslog and recompile, or to switch to syslog-ng.

Comment: Well, that's annoying. Do you happen to already know the value that needs to be changed in order to display in 12-hour time?